# Change reference on existing event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following JavaScript code:

```
var MyGlobalRef = (function () {

    function init(obj1, obj2) {

        prepareEvents(obj1);
        prepareEvents(obj2);

        function prepareEvents(obj) {

            var handleMouseUp = function (evt) {
                // do work with obj
            };

            obj.addEventListener('mouseup', handleMouseUp);
        }
    }
    return {
        init: init
    }
})();
```

In my main page, I'm frequently calling the `init` function like this:

```
function moveNext(){
    MyGlobalRef.init(getNewObj1(), getNewObj2());
}
```

My problem is that on that `moveNext()` function, I tend to replace the existing objects, meaning that there are only 2 objects in the page at all times. However, the more I call `moveNext` the more event listeners get generated. So by the time I `moveNext` 3 times, the mouse up event fires 3 times per one mouse up. The obvious solution is to call `addEventListener` only the first time. However, the problem with this is that `obj` (that is used in the mouse up event) does not update and still references the original `obj`. Also, I failed to use `removeEventListener` because I don't have a reference to the `obj` once it's initiated.

Comment: Let your `init` function to return `destroy` instead of `undefined`. Basically when you call `init` you get back a function `destroy` which you can call to execute `removeEventListener` for your `obj1` and `obj2`. So that you could call saved `destroy` function right before you call `MyGlobalRef.init`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on my comment. Here is what I envision. You return a `destroy` function as a result of `init` execution

**Solution #1**

```
var MyGlobalRef = (function () {

    function init(obj1, obj2) {

        prepareEvents(obj1);
        prepareEvents(obj2);

        function prepareEvents(obj) {

            var handleMouseUp = function (evt) {
                // do work with obj
            };

            obj.addEventListener('mouseup', handleMouseUp);
        }

        return function() {
          obj1.removeEventListener('mouseup');
          obj2.removeEventListener('mouseup');
        };
    }
    return {
        init: init
    }
})();


// cleanup is a variable stored in your code to run a cleanup on obj1 and obj2 later on

function moveNext(){
    if (cleanup) {
      cleanup();
    }

    cleanup = MyGlobalRef.init(GetNewObj1A(), GetNewObj1A());
}
```

**Solution #2**
Keep reference to `obj1` and `obj2` in closure.

```
var MyGlobalRef = (function () {

    var _obj1;
    var _obj2;

    function init(obj1, obj2) {

        prepareEvents(obj1);
        prepareEvents(obj2);

        function prepareEvents(obj) {

            var handleMouseUp = function (evt) {
                // do work with obj
            };

            obj.addEventListener('mouseup', handleMouseUp);
        }

        _obj1 = obj1;
        _obj2 = obj2;
    }
    function cleanup() {
        if (_obj1) {
          _obj1.removeEventListener('mouseup');
        }

        if (_obj2) {
          _obj2.removeEventListener('mouseup');
        }
    }
    return {
        init: init,
        cleanup: cleanup
    }
})();



function moveNext(){
    MyGlobalRef.cleanup();
    MyGlobalRef.init(GetNewObj1A(), GetNewObj1A());
}
```

Comment: I like solution 2. But the problem is that `removeEventListener` requires passing the function that has been attached. Therefore I need to expand the scope of `handleMouseUp`. However, by doing so I'd lose access to `obj` that is used within the handler. Although solution 2 looks clean but it doesn't work. I guess that the same concept applies to Solution 1

Comment: @yazanpro you can get the clicked object from `evt` and you can move `handleMouseUp` outside of `prepareEvents` in order that you have a reference to the method for `removeEventListener` - hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: I think you're right. Well since this is a very simplified version of my actual code, I guess I have quite a good amount of work ahead of me.

Comment: @yazanpro are you sure Solution #2 does not work because it clearly works in Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/t939majt/1/ you can see that we get an access to the previously defined value

Comment: @anvk The whole dilemma has to do with having an event that gets called automatically. Your example lacks that event.

Comment: I changed your code to have an event where the problem shows. We should get one alert on the mouse click not two. Please have a look if you get a chance. https://jsfiddle.net/t939majt/3/

Comment: @yazanpro Well of course `prepareEvents` was returning undefined. Also in cleanup you need to call `removeListener`. Here is a working updated version https://jsfiddle.net/t939majt/4/

Answer (score -1):

You call prepareEvents before the function, put function prepareEvents(obj) before your init function. Try it.